# How to create multiple entities with TYPEORM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

Almost all tutorials on `typeorm` say that first we need create entities one by one and then connect those entities to the main entity like this :

```
const photo1 = new Photo();
photo1.url = "me.jpg";
await connection.manager.save(photo1);

const photo2 = new Photo();
photo2.url = "me-and-bears.jpg";
await connection.manager.save(photo2);

const user = new User();
user.name = "John";
user.photos = [photo1, photo2];
await connection.manager.save(user);
or alternatively you can do:
const user = new User();
user.name = "Leo";
await connection.manager.save(user);

const photo1 = new Photo();
photo1.url = "me.jpg";
photo1.user = user;
await connection.manager.save(photo1);

const photo2 = new Photo();
photo2.url = "me-and-bears.jpg";
photo2.user = user;
await connection.manager.save(photo2);
```

The problem with this method is that we need to know how many photos we need to create and in my situation , I don't know how many `photo` entities may come with the request payload .

My question is that how can I create `photo` entities by mapping through all of them and set their properties ?